# Chrome requested to change computer

Tags: google-chrome, window, safe-mode

Any attempt to open Chrome shows a UAC window asking for permission to allow it to change the computer. Clicking `Yes` sends it to safe mode but it's oversized and blurry.

Tried most of the suggestions on Chrome support to no success. The shortcut has a blue and yellow shield on the lower right. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: That doesn't sound like Chrome's executable file...  Considering its going to safe mode, it may be rogueware.  Where did you get this file from?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the browser? (We can easily tell if this is really chrome)

Comment: You clicked yes to reboot he computer in safe mode? Or did you run something in elevated mode?

Answer (score 0):

What you described sounds like somebody has checked

- Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution
- Run this program as an administrator

in the program properties under the "Compatibility" section as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of: Properties >> Compatibility]

Make sure all of the checkboxes on that tab are unchecked, then see if the issue is still occurring.

If it is, you probably [aren't opening Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1057659/chrome-requested-to-change-computer#comment1484654_1057659).